# Detecting the row that was clicked using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am wondering how to do the following. I've got a table of `tweets` being pulled in from the `Streaming API`. Each `tr` has a `delete` button associated with it. The idea is that when I click on the `delete` button a pop up box appears prompting the user if they wish to delete the selected row.

The only issue I am having is how I can detect which button is clicked and therefor get the `tweet` associated with that `tr`.

This is my code:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            All Tweets
            <div class="pull-right btn-toolbar">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete_selected">Delete Selected</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover" id="tweets_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select</th>
                        <th>Tweet</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Tweeted at</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach(Tweet::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get() as $tweet)
                    <tr id="{{$tweet->tweet_id}}">
                        <td><a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-danger" name="delete[]">Delete</a></td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->tweet_text}}</td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->screen_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$tweet->created_at}}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the `HTML` for the pop-up:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Warning: Delete Tweet</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you would like to delete this Tweet from the database? 
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">No</a>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the `JQuery`

```
$('#openBtn').click(function(){

            $('#myModal').modal({show:true})

        });
```

Currently all the above code does is when any of the delete buttons is pressed the modal is displayed. I'd like to be able to display information associated with the row the delete button is contained within inside this modal. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `closest` function to find the parent row for the clicked element and save it in a var. Later you can use the var to display information for that row.

```
var clicked_row;
$('.btn-danger').click(function(){
    clicked_row = $(this).closest('tr');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest row to delete button and remove as below:

```
$(".btn-danger").on('click', function(e) {
   if (confirm('Are you sure to delete row?'))
   {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();  
   }  
   else
   {
     return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically re render the table again by deleting the required 'id' from 'Tweet'.

Here is my sample code  I have implemented in my project. I hope it will give U idea to solve Ur problem.

HTML code design

```
    <div>
        <table id="idCartDetailsTable">
            <tr></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Need to be called(deleteCartItems) when delete button is clicked

```
deleteCartItems: function(event){
        cartData.checkinCartData.pop(event.target.id);
        this.renderCheckinCartItems(this.el);        
  }
```

Need to be called(renderCheckinCartItems) in page load by passing the reference of element

```
 renderCheckinCartItems: function (element) {
        $(element).find('#idCartDetailsTable tr').html("");           
        var cartItems = "";       
        for (var i = 0; i < cartData.checkinCartData.length ; i++) {
           cartItems += '<tr id="tr'+cartData.checkinCartData.id+'">'+
                        '</tr>';
        }
        $(element).find('#idCartDetailsTable tr').last().after(cartItems);
  }
```